# Amazon S3 hosted videos won't play on iPhone browsers, but working on android

Tags: android, ios, amazon-s3, video, html5-video

Amazon S3 hosted videos won't play on iPhone browsers, but working on android 
I have a web app and that app I used react-player as video player 
And videos(mp4) hosted to AWS s3 bucket but AWS s3 hosted videos not playing on
iPhone browsers

Comment: if you open the URL to the S3 hosted video in both browsers what happens? Do you have the correct MIME type set for the videos

Comment: It plays in normal browsers and android mobile browsers but only iPhones it not playing, And also MIME-type is correct

Comment: Hi, @Kumara. I have this problem too. Did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you are not specifying the **mime type**. The same issue happened with me while I was using **React Player**.

```
<ReactPlayer url=fileLocation playing />

<ReactPlayer url={[{src: fileLocation, type: 'video/mp4'}]} playing />
```

Adding type attribute solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue and none of the listed solution work for me. I was displaying videos on the site from `S3` but they were not playing on `iOS` and giving issue listed above but one of the video was working without issue. I tried to add `-tag:v hvc1` too but it didn't worked. I compared both videos via `FFmpeg` and found that it was an encoding issue. I was generating video via `FFmpeg` and adding `-brand mp42` in generating the video worked.

In short, it is most probably due to different encoding format although both are of type `video/mp4`.